# About the protonation of guanidines

Tags: organic-chemistry

I am working with the protonation of guanidines.

The structure of these compounds looks like this:

[image]

I know that possibly the protonated-nitrogen will be the double bonded one (that structure conserve resonance), but i am looking for some **experimental or theoretical proof**, and it is not being easy to find a nice one. Ideas or links about this problem (maybe a paper) will be helpful.

Comment: All other lone pairs are delocalized into the $\pi$-system. Try drawing resonance structures.

Comment: In solid state, yes: http://scripts.iucr.org/cgi-bin/paper?a04854

Comment: Also in solution, there's just one signal by proton NMR: http://www.rsc.org/suppdata/cc/c3/c3cc46518g/c3cc46518g.pdf